# "No stages / jobs for this pipeline" when trying to run tests in a GitLab

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration

Here's the code of my YAML file:

```
stages:
  - test

image: node:18.16.0-alpine 

before_script:
  - apk add --no-cache sudo curl build-base g++ libpng libpng-dev jpeg-dev pango-dev cairo-dev giflib-dev python3 firefox

unit_tests:
  stage: test
  script:
    npm test
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - unit-test-reports/
  except:
    - main
  only:
    - unit-tests

api_tests:
  stage: test
  script:
    npm test
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - api-test-reports/
  except:
    - main
  only:
    - api_tests

ui_tests:
  stage: test
  script:
    npm test
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ui-test-reports/
  except:
    - main
  only:
    - ui_tests
```

tried to run the pipeline in GitLab, but always getting an error:
"No stages / jobs for this pipeline" when trying to run tests in a GitLab

I intentionally want to run tests on 3 different pipelines, that's why I specify them in Only

Comment: Kirill, I can't duplicate this report with the above YAML

Are you on a self-hosted GitLab? If so, what version? Are you able to share a repository or pipeline (or even a screenshot).

I have a few of observations that may help with debugging:

I created a project with the above `.gitlab-ci.yml`.  The pipeline syntax is valid. No errors.

Answer (score 0):

Kirill,

I created a demo project for your review, refactoring the provided pipeline quite a bit. However, I have never been able to duplicate your reported issues.

I asked in a comment that may have been missed a couple of questions:

1. Are you on a self-hosted GitLab instance? If so, what version?
2. Can you share a repository or pipeline with logs?

**Demo Project**

[The demo repository.](https://gitlab.com/another15y/no-jobs)

There's a lot to unpack in your question, but I see at least one intention:

> I intentionally want to run tests on three (3) different pipelines, that's why I specify them in `only`

This can be read a couple of ways, but I'm going to guess that the idea is that you want the three (3) jobs, `unit_tests`, `api_tests`, and `ui_tests` to run immediately on pipeline start. You can see this in the image below.

[image: Three jobs executing immediately on pipeline initialization with GitLab DAG needs property.]

This is accomplished with `needs: []` and is [detailed in the documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#needs). The use of `only` in your example is [detailed as well in the documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#onlyrefs--exceptrefs). You'll note that the syntax, `only:refs` means that the job will only run on a branch named for one of the three (3) jobs, e.g., `unit_tests`.

My demo project refactors your pipeline and uses a number of GitLab CI descriptor features to make the jobs easier to read.

1. A `.test-base` job defines the `image`, `stage`, `before_script`, `script`, `needs` and `rules` for each of the test jobs.
2. Each test job, `extends` the `.test-base` job.
3. In the `.test-base:before_script` you'll see that I use a YAML block scalar to make the `apk add` command easier to read and maintain.
4. I removed the use of `only` and `except` (deprecated by GitLab) for `rules`. The `rules` replicate your use of `except:ref` and `only:ref`.

Something you should be aware of: as written, the jobs will consume three (3) runners and each runner will begin by updating the `node:18.16.0-alpine` image. This will slow each job down everytime the jobs run. My immediate recommendation would be to customize a node image with the required packages and publish that image in a registry. Then use that customized image for your jobs. This recommendation is beyond the scope of this answer, but I would begin with a repository and a Dockerfile and publish to Docker Hub under my username. Or publish to GitLab's container registry (if available). My employer hosts a container registry, so I would use that one for all internal GitLab pipelines.

HTH,
Tim